# Highcharts hide series without change legend color

Tags: highcharts

I need to hide serie, but i need to remove hide effect on legend. (turns color to gray)

I tried,

```
serie.setVisible(false, false);
```

or

```
serie.hide();
```

both changes legend color to gray. Probably, I need to use serie.update() to do that. What properties will change in update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set fixed color for texts using [`itemHiddenStyle`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemHiddenStyle).

However, if you want to achieve the same effect on the shape/item, then the easiest would be to wrap method which sets color, to always render color like for visible series:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'colorizeItem', function(p, item) {
       p.call(this, item, true);  // second param, "visible" = true
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lftuhzk/1/